# Kendo Server Side Paging Posting to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-grid

I'm attempting to use server side paging with the Kendo UI Grid, and I'm getting errors that don't seem to be documented anywhere.

The error I receive is:

```
Unhandled exception at line 11, column 15140 in kendo.all.min.js
0x800a138f JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'slice' of undefined or null reference.
```

Per documentation and other examples I've found online, I bind my kendo grid using:

```
var postData = { "searchTerm" : searchTerm, "targetDB" : targetDB, "searchObj" : searchObj }

var grid = $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 40
    },
    dataSource: {
        error: function (e) {
            if (e.errors !== false) {
                $("#errorContainer").html(e.errors);
            }
        },
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: servicePath,
                dataType: "json",
                data: postData,
                type: "POST"
            }
        },
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: {
            total: "total",
            data: "data"
        }
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
        var end = new Date().getTime();
        var time = end - start;
        console.log("Time taken: " + time);
        $("#loading").hide();
        $("#grid1").show();
        $("#totalTimeBadge").html(time + " milliseconds");
        $("#totalCountBadge").html(this.dataSource.total() + " items");
        $("#propertyCountBadge").html($(".k-header").length + " properties");
        logTimes(time, this.dataSource.total(), $(".k-header").length);
    }
});
```

The reason I use a post is (as you can probably guess) I'm implementing a search feature, and use the Kendo Grid to post the search criteria and the target DB I want to search on (there are two possibilities).

I have run the returning JSON through jslint and verified that it is valid JSON the structure of which is:

```
[{
    "total": 50053,
    "data": [{objects}]
}]
```

If I need to post a larger an actual excerpt of the JSON I can, it's a bit long to post here.

I was tracking the answer to this question here: [Error while implementing basic paging in Kendo UI Grid in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989548/error-while-implementing-basic-paging-in-kendo-ui-grid-in-asp-net)

But this question does not use the Kendo grid to post as well as retrieve items (no idea if that makes a difference) and I have also verified that the only answer to this question doesn't apply in my instance.

If I take out the `total` datafield and only return the raw data of my response, the grid binds just fine, but I need to incorporate server side paging.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Update**

As per a suggestion below, I attempted to change my controller from returning a straight string to utilizing a DataSourceResult:

```
public ActionResult DataSourceResult()
    {
        string dataStr = "[{\"NAME\": \"0720-FI-1081\", \"DESCRIPTION\": \"HP FLARE HEADER DISTRIBUTION\"},{\"NAME\": \"0720-FIC-1002\",\"DESCRIPTION\": null}]";
        DataSourceResult result = new DataSourceResult();
        result.Data = dataStr;
        result.Total = 50;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        return Content(json, "application/json");
    }
```

Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After swapping emails with Telerik support, here is what I found and works:

The JSON being returned can't be wrapped in `[]` although this is valid JSON. Instead, the following form works.

```
{
"Data":
    [
        {"Name":"John","Description":"None"},
        {"Name":"Jane","Description":"StillNone"}
    ],
    "Total":50,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null
}
```

This is what the `DataSourceResult` returns. A flat string that works as well is:

```
{
"Total": "50",
"Data": [
     {"NAME": "0720-FI-1081", "DESCRIPTION": "HP FLARE HEADER DISTRIBUTION"},
     {"NAME": "0720-FIC-1002","DESCRIPTION": null}
    ]
}
```

The key points here being that the entire JSON result cannot be wrapped in `[]`, however the Data field of the response *must* be wrapped in `[]`.

With the above strings, the grid declaration has to have a minor edit from the OP above:

```
schema: {
        total: "Total",
        data: "Data"
    }
```

As both fields are capitalized.

This is not documented anywhere, it's just something you have to know.

Cheers

Comment: "This is not documented anywhere, it's just something you have to know." Why Kendo makes me rage everytime I have to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced a similar situation, the only valid solution to this for us was to use DataSourceResult object while returning rather than returning list of search result and total record count.

Have a look at the code we used:

```
  List<SearchResult> lst = GetSearchResult(filterCriteriaPassed);// Your search logic

  DataSourceResult result = null;

  // Reason to set the page as 1 for DataSource result was that we were only 
  // retriveing single page records so we had to set first page to show manually.
  request.Page = 1; 
  result = lst.ToDataSourceResult(request);

  result.Total = totalRecords;

  return Json(result);
```

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue else please mark this as Answer.

Comment: Rather than displaying the total at databound, it's better to get the total via **http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates**. I assume that might solve your issue.